# Parse.com some columns not updated on segue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to update a few columns on parse. Here , only `gotpromoCode` gets updated before segue . But if I come back from the next view controller, on the same button click function gets called again and other columns `promoCode and senderUserId` are updated. I have set breakpoints and seen that the code for updating the columns is called before segue for these two columns but first time they are still not getting updated.

```
 var promoCode = ""

//if promocode is nil
if ((self.currentUser["promoCode"]) == nil)
{
    let nameString = self.firstname.text!+self.lastname.text!

    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("createPromoCode", withParameters: ["nameString" : nameString]){ response, error in
        if let error = error {

            print (error)
        }
        else {

            print("Invite sent")

            print("the invitation code is: \(String(response!))")

            promoCode = String(response!)

            PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(promoCode, forKey: "promoCode")
        }
    }

}

//validating promo code
if ( self.promocodeText.text?.isEmpty == false )// && PFUser.currentUser()!["gotpromoCode"] == nil )
{

    var query1 = PFQuery(className:"_User")
    query1.whereKey("promoCode", equalTo:self.promocodeText.text!)
    query1.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(self.promocodeText.text, forKey: "gotpromoCode")
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects {
                for object in objects {
                    print(object.objectId)

                    // self.senderUserId = object.objectId!
                    PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(object.objectId!, forKey: "senderUserId")
                    print("senderUserId is: \(object.objectId!)")

                }
            }


        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
            self.displayAlert("Error!", body: "Promo Code does not exists")

        }

    }

}


PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.goToAccount, sender: self)

    } else {
        // There was a problem, check error.description
    }
}
```

I have checked the values in breakpoints and am out of ideas why this is happening.

Comment: Is this code all in the same function?

Comment: In the first case you are creating the promo code in the background via cloud code but later you save the user outside of that completion block,

Comment: please, provide the whole class code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by saving the result after setting the values.

```
  PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()
```

so I used this like

```
PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(object.objectId!, forKey: "senderUserId")
 PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()
```

similarly for the promoCode , then it worked.